# Pandas Splitting Columns Vertically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        fname          lname                           email
0         Homer        Simpson       homer.simpson@example.com
1         Jane         Doe           jane.doe@example.com
2         Samuel       Tom           "samuel.tom@example.com, kate.leo@example.com, billy.billerson@example.com"
```

What I want is this:

```
         fname          lname                           email
0         Homer        Simpson       homer.simpson@example.com
1         Jane         Doe           jane.doe@example.com
2         Samuel       Tom           samuel.tom@example.com
3                                     kate.leo@example.com
4                                    billy.billerson@example.com
```

Without names in the first and last name in the bottom 2 rows.

Any suggestions on how to split this vertically like that?

Comment: What do you want it to be after split? a list or an individual cell?

Comment: Additional rows in the dataframe, I edited my post to reflect that better by adding numbers on the index. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.pop` with `join`ing `right`:

```
new_df = df.join(df.pop("email").str.split(", +").explode(True), how="right")
print(new_df.fillna("")) # To show nan as empty
```

Output:

```
    fname    lname                        email
0   Homer  Simpson    homer.simpson@example.com
1    Jane      Doe         jane.doe@example.com
2  Samuel      Tom       samuel.tom@example.com
3                          kate.leo@example.com
4                   billy.billerson@example.com
```

Comment: "Explode takes 1 position argument but 2 were given"

Comment: @LunchBox ah that's new in `pandas-1.1.0`. Can you afford to upgrade `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

This is do called `explode`

```
out = df.assign(email = df['email'].str.split(',')).explode('email')
```